# How to edit directives previously entered?

Tags: cdap, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am new to CDAP / Data Fusion.  I have created a preparation / wrangler which has included a set of directives.  I find that I now wish to edit these previously entered directives but can't seem to find out how to perform this task.

For example, in the following screen shot, how might I use the UI to change the data type for the `quantity` column to be a float?  My current technique is to delete directives 4, 5 and 6 and re-enter but I have to believe that there are better editing techniques than this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on ‘x’ will delete a directive. You can’t delete only one from the middle.

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  Can you confirm that I can NOT edit a directive in the Wrangler UI but instead can only delete entries?  Also, if I delete an entry in the middle of the directives list, then that deletes all subsequent entries?

Comment: Correct, if you edit / delete a directive in the middle, it could possibly affect the directives following that. To ensure correctness we delete all directives below the directive being deleted. We can get smart about it by analyzing directives downstream to see for any impacts - we have that as future work.